# Output redirection does not work correctly when script contains sed

Tags: bash, sed, stdout

I have following file structure:

```
-script.sh
-directory (empty directory)
```

`script.sh` code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start"

find . -type f | xargs sed -r -i '' "s/a/b/g"

echo 'After find/sed'
```

I run `../script.sh | tee out.log` from `directory` and get following results:

- terminal output

```
Start
After find/sed
```

- `cat out.log`

```
Stbrt
```

But I expected to see the same result for `cat out.log` as for terminal output.

1. Why terminal output and `out.log` differ?
2. How can script affect content of `out.log`? Isn't it created after script is finished? (we see it is affected: `Start` -> `Stbrt`)

Comment: What is the output of `hexdump -C out.log` `if it should be created after script is finished?` No, surely the output file has to be created _before_ running the script.

Comment: @KamilCuk, didn't get the point. Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why terminal output and out.log differ?

`sed -i` creates a temporary file and then *moves* the temporary file into file to be modified.

`tee` *opens* the file and writes to the file descriptor.

The file `out.log` opened by `tee` is no longer there. `sed` sees the first line of the file, modifies it, and moves the new file to `out.log`. `tee` continues writing the second line to the file that is no longer reachable through the directory inode. You are seeing the file modified by `sed`.

> How can script affect content of out.log if it should be created after script is finished?

Script finishing execution and creation of `out.log` file are unsequenced. They can happen in any order, which depends on which process get's CPU and kernel time and on I/O time. In your case, `tee` creates the file first and writes there the first line of output, before `sed` can execute, so `sed` sees the file and replaces it.